# How to install pdfkit (python module) in windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10, pdfkit

I install pdfkit using pip (`pip install pdfkit`).

Then i install wkhtmltopdf from [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

But when i try to run the following code:

```
import pdfkit

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe')
pdfkit.from_url('https://www.google.com', 'C:\\Users\\Χρήστος\\Desktop\\out-test.pdf', configuration=config)
```

An error oqqurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_pdf.py", line 4, in <module>
    pdfkit.from_url('https://www.google.com', 'C:\\Users\\Χρήστος\\Desktop\\out-test.pdf', configuration=config)
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 26, in from_url
    return r.to_pdf(output_path)
  File "C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 156, in to_pdf
    raise IOError('wkhtmltopdf reported an error:\n' + stderr)
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Loading pages (1/6)
QPainter::begin(): Returned false============================] 100%
Error: Unable to write to destination
Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.
```

Any advice would be useful.

I also run the code with administration priviledges.

**Edit:** From wkhtmltopdf site:

> How do I use it? Download a precompiled binary or build from source
> Create your HTML document that you want to turn into a PDF (or image)
> Run your HTML document through the tool. For example, if I really like
> the treatment Google has done to their logo today and want to capture
> it forever as a PDF:
>
> wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf

So i tried this:

```
cd C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

Didn't work, but when I run it with admininstration priviledges the pdf was make.
So the pdfkit module must open wkhtmltopdf with admin priviledges.

Comment: looks like it is not an installation problem but your destination is not writable. Try different destination.

Answer (score 0):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1966) on GitHub, seems you have to specify the full path (eg. 'C://foo/bar')

Probably because the script doesn't have permission to write in the folder where it lives:
`C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py`

You gave it a relative path, so in runtime, it will try to create a file:
`C:\Users\Χρήστος\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\out.pdf`

Comment: i notice about this issue.
That's not the problem.

Comment: There is another github issue: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2934
discussing from target folder to TCP/IP issues. Try troubleshooting and let us know

Comment: @DataMonger Question eddited.